# Transpose GROUPS of QUERY results to single column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I'm having difficulty `TRANSPOSE`'ing my `QUERY` results.  The results are in groups of five and already transposed once from rows to columns.  Now that each result is in columns of 5 rows, I want to combine *those* results to a single column, preferably with a space between each group.

Here is what I'm currently getting:
[image]

And this is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

[Here is the link to my sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ilbEtcrbBBh7HdwQYIxMubPVYCJrd4m4pd9vsFTWjAI/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I don't think it's _possible_ without `google-sheet-script`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After figuring out a little more what you were going for on your sample sheet, I came up with this formula.  it's a bit more complex than it would normally be for a retabulation like this because you wanted it limited to the first 5 players from your squad tab.

=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(QUERY(VLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(COUNTA('Squad Compositions'!B4:B)*6,1,0)/6+4,{ROW('Squad Compositions'!B4:B),'Squad Compositions'!B4:B,ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IFERROR(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(TRIM(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF('Squad Compositions'!E4:S="",,'Squad Compositions'!E4:S&CHAR(10))),,15))),CHAR(10)&" ",0)),9^99,5),IF(ROW('Squad Compositions'!B4:B),"|")},MOD(SEQUENCE(COUNTA('Squad Compositions'!B4:B)*6,1,0),6)*{0,1}+{2,3}),"where Col2 is not null"),"|",""))

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here the formula, in B10:

```
= arrayformula(
    { transpose
      ( split(join(rept(",",6),
        filter('Squad Compositions'!B4:B,'Squad Compositions'!B4:B<>"")) 
        ,",",true,false)
      ),(
      { transpose(split(substitute(textjoin( "%",false,
        { filter ('Squad Compositions'!E4:I,'Squad Compositions'!B4:B<>""),
          left(filter('Squad Compositions'!E4:E&"",'Squad Compositions'!B4:B<>""),0)
        } )& "$","%$",""),"%",true,false))
      })
    }
  )
```

Comment: hats off! awesome!

Comment: Thank you very much for the formula!  It works great until it gets to a cell/team name with commas.  Trying to figure out how to change the delimiter, but so far, no luck.

Comment: Yes, because if the comma are included, the formula Will not work